# Generate PDF from more 1 checkbox

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox

Here is my issue. I want to choose some entries and post them to PDF document. When I choose 1 entry I getting document but I have blank document when I choose more 1 entries.

```
echo '<form action="check.php" method="POST">';

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('error! Not connected with server mysql!');

    mysql_select_db('mybase') or die('error! Not connected!');
    mysql_query("set names cp1251");
    $stid = mysql_query('select * from Authors');

    for ($c=0; $c<mysql_num_rows($stid); $c++)
    {
    $f = mysql_fetch_array($stid);
    echo "$f[AuthorName]";
    echo '<input type="checkbox"  name="check[]" value="'.$f['AuthorName'].'"> <br></br>';
    }

    ?>
        <p><input type="submit" value="POST;" name="B1"></p>
    </form>
```

check.php:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fpdf17/font/');
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
$check_del  = $_POST['check'];
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
for($i=0; $i<count($check_del); $i++)
{
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$check_del[i],15);
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have left off the $ in front of the i on the following line.

```
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$check_del[i],15);
```

I hope this helps.